# JS Creating a Timer To Hide Image Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I'm trying to create a image slideshow that plays through all of the images and on the last one fade away and no longer show any images for another 10 seconds, then after 10 seconds it starts all over again. Currently I have it stopping on the last image but it doesn't do anything after that and just gets stuck. Not really all that sure on how to accomplish something like this so any and all help is really appreciated! Below is the JS if any other script is needed please let me know!

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   // var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex >= slides){
        setTimeout(function(){ slideIndex = 1; }, 10000);
    }
    /*for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }*/
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}
```

**UPDATE:** setInterval

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

var myPause = setInterval(function(){ showSlides() }, 10000);

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        myPause;
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
    clearInterval(myPause);
}
```

Comment: You're already familiar with setTimeout, please also check out setInterval ;)

Comment: @BillyNate So i tried that out but now i seem to have it just continuously playing with no pause

Comment: @kyle : you are calling myPause method without (), just see my asnwer below for more details.

Comment: @Kyle : Rest of you code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BillyNate already said, `setInterval` makes it work the way you want. To repeat the slideshow with a 10 second break inbetween, you need to hide the last slide and then repeat the slideshow after 10 seconds by setting a timeout.

The animation can be applied where the last slide gets set to `display: none`.

```js
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

function switchSlides() {
  var slideCount = slides.length;
  var i = 0;
  
  // Set first slide visible
  slides[i].style.display = "block";
  
  // Switch slide every 10 seconds
  var switchInterval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    if (i < slideCount) {
      slides[i-1].style.display = "none";
      slides[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      clearInterval(switchInterval);

      // Hide last slide (--> fade out image)
      slides[i-1].style.display = "none";
      
      // Wait 10 seconds, then repeat switchSlides
      setTimeout(switchSlides, 10000);
    }
  }, 10000);
}

switchSlides();
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="mySlides" src="http://unsplash.it/200?image=10">
<img class="mySlides" src="http://unsplash.it/200?image=20">
<img class="mySlides" src="http://unsplash.it/200?image=30">
```

Answer (score 3):

You're really close. Just using `setInterval` should be enough.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    setInterval(function() {
      slides[slideIndex].style.display = "none";
     slideIndex ++;
      if(slideIndex >= slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
      }
    }, 10000);
}
```

```css
img { display: block; width: 100% }
```

```html
<img class="mySlides" src="http://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?q=75" />
<img class="mySlides" src="http://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417436026361-a033044d901f?q=75" />
<img class="mySlides" src="http://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1414502622871-b90b0bec7b1f?q=75" />
```

Comment: Hey Billy think I may of not been very clear but I'm looking to have it fade out on the last image and no longer display an image for X amount of time. After said X amount of time I'm looking to have the slideshow reaper.

Comment: As long as you want the "blank slide" to have the same amount of time as the other slides, you can keep using `setInterval` all the same. I've changed the code accordingly.